# Definition of Female Empowerment

Tags: meaning, word-usage, terminology, vocabulary, twentieth-century-english

Does anyone have a good definition of female empowerment?

It'd be extremely helpful if this came as a quote. Please link if possible!

Comment: [***Female empowerment** means putting education, authority, decision-making, capital, prestige, and influence **in the hands of women.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22female+empowerment+means%22)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a definition of a political term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say **"empowerment of women"** or **"women's empowerment"**, instead.

The United Nations Entity for Gender Equality and the Empowerment of Women, also known as UN Women, is a United Nations entity working for the **empowerment of women.** [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UN_Women)

> [**women's empowerment**](http://www.selfgrowth.com/articles/Articles_Women_Empowerment.html) refers to increasing the spiritual, political, social or economic strength of women.
>
> - Having decision-making power of their own
> - Having access to information and resources for taking proper decision
> - Having a range of options from which you can make choices (not just yes/no, either/or.)
> - Ability to exercise assertiveness in collective decision making
> - Having positive thinking on the ability to make change
> - Ability to learn skills for improving one's personal or group power.
> - Ability to change others’ perceptions by democratic means.
> - Involving in the growth process and changes that is never ending and self-initiated
> - Increasing one's positive self-image and overcoming stigma

- in theory, microfinance services combined with interventions **to empower women** lead to positive benefits, including enhanced...
- ...explains that **'empowering women** works as a catalyst in development'...